# Como digitalizar uma assinatura com java

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou necessitando obter a assinatura em um documento mas não gostaria de imprimir o mesmo.
Alguém sabe indicar um Pad de assinatura que funcione com o primefaces ?

Comment: Tentou o Signature? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/signature.xhtml

Comment: Isso mesmo Marcus. Eu já tinha procurado e não tinha visto.
Põe como resposta para fechar o chamado.

Comment: Pode tentar o [Signature](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/signature.xhtml). É bem fácil de usar.